# Ansible - using json imported from Consul

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, consul

I have a json content on Consul that I import to my playbook. The json contains account names and passwords:

```
{
    "account_1": "password_1",
    "account_2": "password_2",
    "account_3": "password_3"
}
```

After registering it to variable I wish to be able to use every user name and password. Since these jsons may contain different numbers of entries, I was hoping I could use with_items for this. Can someone help me out?

Debugging the whole json works with no issues:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "accountsDataFromConsul.data.Value": {
        "account_1": "password_1",
        "account_2": "password_2",
        "account_3": "password_3"
    }
}
```

I try to get to individual entries (user names and passwords). I tried the below code, but it returned only user names:

```
- debug:
    var: item
  with_items: "{{accountsDataFromConsul.data.Value}}"
```

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=account_1) => {
    "item": "account_1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=account_2) => {
    "item": "account_2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=account_3) => {
    "item": "account_3"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map data is not iterable via ansible loops.

Take a look at the [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) filter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
- name: Lets munge some data
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: false
  vars:
    my_dict:
      key_one: value_one
      key_two: value_two
    my_json: '{"key_one": "value_one", "key_two": "value_two"}'
  tasks:
  - name: Iterate over a dict
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
    loop: "{{ my_dict | dict2items }}"

  - name: Iterate over json
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
    loop: "{{ my_json | from_json | dict2items }}"


PLAY [Lets munge some data] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Iterate over a dict] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'key_one', 'value': 'value_one'}) => {
    "msg": "key_one value_one"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'key_two', 'value': 'value_two'}) => {
    "msg": "key_two value_two"
}

TASK [Iterate over json] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'key_one', 'value': 'value_one'}) => {
    "msg": "key_one value_one"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'key_two', 'value': 'value_two'}) => {
    "msg": "key_two value_two"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Right, dict2items should work. Now I need to find a way to transform my json into dictionary.

Comment: Try using the from_json filter. "{{ json_data | from_json | dict2items }}"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Vladimir and Nick. That works perfectly. The only thing I had to do was using from_json on my Consul output.

```
- set_fact:
    jsonvar: "{{accountsDataFromConsul.data.Value | from_json}}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{jsonvar | dict2items}}"
```

Comment: Updated original to include json example

Answer (score 0):

> to use every user name and password

The play below

```
vars:
  accountsDataFromConsul:
    data:
      Value:
        account_1: password_1
        account_2: password_2
        account_3: password_3
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "key: {{ item.key }} value: {{ item.value }}"
    loop: "{{ accountsDataFromConsul.data.Value|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged):

```
"msg": "key: account_1 value: password_1"
"msg": "key: account_3 value: password_3"
"msg": "key: account_2 value: password_2"
```